# How to determine if code for an IPython custom magic is executing on startup

Tags: ipython, startup

I have a .py file, defining a custom magic, in the /.ipython/profile_default/startup directory, but the intended magic is not being installed.  Is there a way to determine where the fault lies?  Where is execution failing?  Other, very simple .py files in that directory are executing fine.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer appears to be 'no,' there is no way to see what is happening during ipython startup...no log file keeping track of what is happening.

But I did solve my problem.

Opened a jupyter notebook.  With the %load magic, copied the code for the custom magic into a cell.  Copied the code into a code cell and ran it.  Found I needed to install pySerial, and did so.  Voila, custom magic now available.  (Still have to find out if it works as intended.)